# %parameter% pattern Search on sql and php

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, search

I have this worpress plugin code:

```
public function parse_search( $search, $include_additional ) {
    $fields = $this->get_searchable_fields( $include_additional );
    $where  = '';

    foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
        if ( $where ) {
            $where .= ' OR';
        }

        $field = explode( '.', $field );
        $field = implode( '`.`', $field );
        $where .= ' `' . $field . '` LIKE ' . $this->wpdb->prepare( "%s", '%' . $search . '%' ) . '';
    }

    $where = apply_filters( 'wpim_parse_search', $where, $search );

    return '(' . $where . ')';
}
```

It creates the parameters to search for. For now it only finds me the full words: for example (if i search for "TTI1506a" it finds me the product) but I want that if I search for "TTI" without the "1506a" it still finds me the product. How can I change this function?

I tried replacing the LIKE with WHERE and it didn't change anything. I'm not used to sql and php, any help?

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow, please **Edit** your question and use the tag which correspond to your database: MySQL, MariaDB, PgSQL, etc. [tag:sql] may be too vague for your question.